# Annoying tag description popup

Tags: feature-request

When the pointer hovers over a tag, a tag popup appears. This is fine if you move the pointer to the tag, but it is a nuisance if you scroll the page and the tag slips under the pointer. Can you work it so that scrolling doesn't trigger the popup, but moving the pointer still does?

Comment: Since this is a feature-request that will be about the whole site, may I suggest proposing this on [the global meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

**No, please don't.**

I rather have a consistent site that always shows these descriptions when my cursor is on the tag, than one were these descriptions sometimes don't pop-up. Adding this feature will cause a lot of unnecessary confusion.

These tag buttons are really small. If occasionally my pointer ends up on one of the tags after a scroll, I am willing to just move my mouse a bit.